# Return value from swift function with background code

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

The function below is only returning false, probably because the **user.singUpInBackgroundWithBlock** is happening in background.

Is there anyway that I can get the intended return value from the function?

```
var returnFlag:Bool = false

func signUpAction(email:String, password:String) -> Bool
{
        let user = PFUser()
        user.username = email
        user.password = password

        user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as? NSString
                print(errorString!)
                // INTENDED RETURN
                self.returnFlag = false
            } else {
                // INTENDED RETURN                    
                self.returnFlag = true 
            }
        }
        return self.returnFlag
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, the function will return false because the block is probably not called on the main thread.

This is an ideal scenario to use NSNotification. Do not pass a return value, instead post a notification once the login action is complete.

**Sample Code :**

Somewhere early in your view controller lifecycle, preferably viewdidload. Register your class to observer for login success and login failed notifications.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("LoginFailedFunc:"), name: "loginFailed", object: nil)
```

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("loginSuccessFunc:"), name: "loginSuccess", object: nil)

In your login function, post a notification based on valid or invalid login.

```
func signUpAction(email:String, password:String){

let user = PFUser()
user.username = email
user.password = password

user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
        let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as? NSString
        print(errorString!)
        // INTENDED RETURN
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("loginFailed", object: self)
        self.returnFlag = false
    } else {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("loginSuccess", object: self)
        self.returnFlag = true
    }
  }
}
```

Finally remember to stop observing notificaitons, when no longer required.